# How to set font color for action menu items in Material night theme?

Tags: android

[image]

Where do I change the text color for menu items?

This is what I get when I run a newly created project using Navigation drawer activity as the template and my device (Galaxy S20) has night mode enabled.

values-night/themes.xml does not seem to have an option for this.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Test3" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Tried adding android:actionMenuTextColor but it has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve it after losing a few hours looking at the wrong place...

In the generated app_bar_main.xml where the action bar is added to the layout, there's

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppName.AppBarOverlay">
```

In themes.xml there's an empty style for it

```
<style name="Theme.Test3.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

To change the text of action manu items, add the textColor parameter to it:

```
<style name="Theme.AppName.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

This style can be added to both values/themes.xml and values-night/themes.xml to have different colors for the dark and light themes.